# What are the most efficient ways for rendering bitmap fonts using a VBO?

Tags: opengl, vbo, bitmap-fonts

What are the most efficient ways for rendering bitmap fonts using a vertex buffer object?

These are the ways that I know at the moment (I don't know about the efficiency):

1. Creating a massive VBO and storing data of textured quads (one texture for all characters and one quad for a letter in text).
2. Also creating a VBO for all text that needs to be rendered, but with bigger quads and textures. Texture size would be equal to the GPU limit or smaller if it would be possible to fit the text in a smaller texture without reducing the quality.
3. Creating a one not that big VBO with textured quad data of all characters. And rendering by multiple draw calls (per letter).

I think you should split the answer for dynamic and static rendering.

Comment: I would add to this that you should consider caching rendered strings in textures. You can reduce the number of vertices necessary to draw a string with say 512 characters from 2048 to 4. You will have to resort to one of the 3 things you proposed initially to render the string the first time or change its formatting / scaling, but after you do that you can just use the cached texture. It will tremendously cut down on redundant vertex calculations.

Comment: take a look at freetype-gl lib.It uses as single VBO for text rendering with fully programmable pipeline.